# Onclick on href in html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to make a button that will redirect me to another page.

the code:

```
 <div align="right" ><input type="submit" id="logout" onclick="location.href=/login?dis=yes" value="Sign Out" ></div><BR>
```

but when i press the button, i dont get any redirection to the other page.

any idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your current code, even if the syntax is fixed by adding quotation marks, creates a button that does not work when JavaScript is disabled. The simpler and safer approach is a small HTML form:

```
<form action="/login">
<input type=hidden name=dis value=yes>
<input type=submit value="Sign Out">
</form>
```

To achieve the desired styling, you could add the following stylesheet:

```
form { display: inline; float: right; }
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps try this using a type="button" and put quotes around the location.

```
<div align="right"><input type="button" id="logout" onclick="location.href='/login?dis=yes'" value="Sign Out" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use

```
<input type="submit" />
```

because this is used to post the form, instead you should use

```
<input type="button" onclick='location.href="/login?dis=yes"'/>
```

for redirection or plain anchor tag

```
<a href="/login?dis=yes">Sign Out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is invalid.

Use this:

```
<div align="right" ><input type="submit" id="logout" onclick="location.href='/login?dis=yes'" value="Sign Out" ></div><BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Set the target to Window.Location so you get the right target changed.
- add return false; so that the submit button does not try to submit the form.
- Put the URL in single quotes to avoid parsing errors.

> <input type="submit" id="logout" onclick="window.location.href='/login?dis=yes';return false;" value="Sign Out">

The main reason that your button,  as designed, will not work is because it is a "Submit" button.    When you click on this it is trying to do the submit action after running your onclick action, essentially ignoring the onclick action.

You can fix this by using a type="button" button, or the above solution I listed if you must use a "submit" button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.location='/login?dis=yes';
```

as

```
        <div align="right" >
<input type="submit" id="logout" 
    onclick="window.location='/login?dis=yes';" value="Sign Out" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you the same thing everyone else has. Instead of using:
    `location.herf` you should use:
    `window.location`
Hope this helps you!